# Python - using the values obtained in a for loop to carry out calculations

Tags: python, loops, numpy

This is part of my progamme:

```
q = np.array([2,3,3])
a = np.array([6.0,8.0,10.0])
b = np.array([3.0,3.0,5.0])
c= np.array([0,4.0,8.0])

i = range(0,len(a))
j = range(0,len(c))
for x in i:
    for y in j:
        if a[x] > c[y] and a[x] < (c + b)[y]:
            d = b[y] - (c[y] + b[y] - a[x])
            e = d, b[y] - d
            print y, e
```

This will give me:

```
1 [ 2.  1.]
2 [ 2.  3.]
```

Then I would want to use these 2 sets of values to carry out more calculations, but it will only use the first set of values when I use y and e. How can I use both sets of values?

```
            q = np.insert(q, np.array(y) + 1, x[y])
            b = list(b)
            b[int(np.array(y)):int(np.array(y) + 1)] = list(e)
            b = np.array(b)
            c = np.insert(c, np.array(y) + 1, d + e[y])
            print q
            print b
            print c
```

This gives me:

```
[2 3 3 3] 
[ 0.  4.  6.  8.] 
[ 3.  2.  1.  5.]
```

my output I want:

```
[2 3 3 3 3]
[ 3. 2. 1. 2. 3.]
[ 0. 4. 6. 8. 10.]
```

Comment: You are using x to represent two different values (an array and an element of i).  These should have different variable names or you will have problems.

Comment: sorry, I have put the wrong variable in, it shouldn't be 'x'. I have made it 'q' now.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are trying to alter the numpy array in-place when looping.  First, you shouldn't do that.  Second, you are  looping over a range, not the values themselves.  Changing the values later doesn't change the range since it is already created.  Third, you can't change the size of a numpy array in-place to begin with, so even if you were looping over the values, it wouldn't work.  If you want to insert or delete values in-place, you need to use a list.  But again, don't do that, it isn't safe.